# Facebook API for getting public status and comments of any user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Like minormonitor, I need to monitor children's facebook but I will only track the children's public status and comments. Facebook's API seems to only provide the data when only login credentials of the target provided. How can the facebook status and comments be tracked without providing the login credentials and without requiring target to like on some apps.

Comment: For that you have to use facebook apis and you can't get status information of a facebook user without credentials just think about it why should facebook give you their user's status information without credentials?

Comment: We can check other's public profile with only their username or email, so whay facebook can't provide that in their api's??